# NetSuite Rest API - Sales Order Refunds

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am very new to netsuite, I am using NetSuite Api to get the sales order, In the sales order object, i can see almost all the information except refund. I don't see any refund object there. Is there different call to get the refunds?
Currently I am sending following request from postman
{{REST_SERVICES}}/record/v1/salesOrder/12274116?expandSubResources=true

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to query netsuite using the SUITESQL and then send a SQL query to run. ex:
URL/services/rest/query/v1/suiteql

and then just send a simple sql query:

select * from table

From that moment you can check the fields being returned and see the things a bit more easily.